# Library for Docker Remote API v1.24 for Go?

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Hi is there any library that I can use for example to use the Types existing in [Docker Remote API v1.24](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/), for example I have this function that returns a service type

```
func GetServices() docker.Services {
    res, _ := client.Get("https:10.0.1.10:2376/services") // client previously created
    js, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    var Services docker.Services

    _ = json.Unmarshal(js, &Services)
    return Services
}
```

here I am assuming that there exists a library docker that contains these types, and this what I need can any one help? previously I used [go-dockerclient](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the official docker API client:

https://github.com/docker/engine-api

For instance, [here's how](https://github.com/docker/engine-api/blob/master/client/service_list_test.go) you would retrieve the list of services using this library.